# What are some disadvantages for a hashmap with timestamp as key?

Tags: algorithms, hashing

"What are some problems that can arise from using a HashMap with timestamp as keys"?

I, for one, do not see any major issues with this kind of "setup".

Is this "setup" a no-go/an anti-pattern/something that should not be done? 
What are the things to look out for?
What problems does this setup have?

PS : it was in interview questions, as somebody mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like an interview question? FWIW, I guess you mean timestamp/value pairs are given, a Hashmap was suggested as a container for this, and the question is about alternatives for the container type "Hashmap", not alternatives for the key type "Timestamp"?

Comment: close enough @DocBrown. it was an interview question and the main question was "what problems do you see with this setup / can the timestamp as key cause major issues"?

Comment: It's a rather daft question. If you want to lookup information based on an exact timestamp, fast, then a hash map with timestamp as key is perfect for that. I've never felt the need to do this, but if I did, I'd use a hashmap with timestamp as key. Works perfectly fine. Of course you don't want to hash based on information that changes. If the timestamp of an object can change, you'll need to update the hash table every time. But that is nothing particular about a time stamp.

Comment: @gnasher729 yeah. imagine getting this during an interview...

Answer (score 6):

My first reaction would be about range queries. Like finding the value right after/before a given timestamp.

Looking up a value requires that you have the exact timestamp, if you miss be 1 times the granularity of the timestamp you will not get the value you are looking for. When timestamps are granular to the millisecond or nanosecond that gets messy.

Another downside that is easily remedied is that it's possible that the accuracy of the timestamp divided by the granularity is not prime relative to the size of the backing table. Meaning that `timestamp % table_size` does not spread evenly across the buckets leading to more collisions. This is easily solved by doing some bit mixing of the timestamp before the modulo operation.

The alternative is a ordered container. A sorted array or a tree of some description. Which one is best depends on the actual operations and other constraints.

Comment: i reckon "granularity" could be considered as the biggest concern. if it is too high, the elements are spread in the internal array too much (there could be too many empty "spaces" in the keys container if the granularity is too high)

Comment: @Belun read the third paragraph again, that issue is fairly easily fixed by a bit of extra work on the key to move the information down into the least significant bits while converting to the index.

Comment: so, things to look out for : 1.reduce granularity to make sure you have hits during searches (map.get(timestamp)); this also reduces empty spaces between keys (thus the size of the keys container); 2. make sure the data is spread as evenly as possible in the data structure; 3. introduce an extra step to transform that timestamp into an index/hashcode (do not use it raw). in the end, the main thing to look for (which is generally related to hash-maps) is how the data is spread across the indexes/keys; balance between key granularity and collisions

Comment: You've missed my main point, you have to look at the **types of operations** you are going to do on the container to decide what type of container you want to use. Hashmap is not well suited for most operations you want to have index on timestamps.

Answer (score 4):

Hashing works best when you can expect keys to be unique. Timestamps might seem like they are unique but there are many cases where they aren't. The same event might happen in two places at the same time. One event might be timestamped in two places at different times with the same timestamp because the clocks aren't in sync.

You can mitigate the likelihood of the same clock stamping two events the same way by increasing precision, mili seconds, pico seconds, etc. but if events happen whenever they feel like happening your risk of the time stamps matching is still not zero.

The [UUID standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) deal with this issue by adding additional information like the MAC address of the node. Following a business rule on that node not to issue two UUIDs with the same time can enforce uniqueness. But now you're forcing reality to fit your expectations, not reporting what really happened.

The fundamental problem is that any timestamp of a fixed length can be forced to be identical to another if the events happen close enough together. It's called the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

The same problem is faced by any hash of the timestamp. A good hash avoids collisions. If the size of the hash reduces the bits too much you get the same problem. Good hashing algorithms mitigate this and might need to be chosen with hashing timestamps in mind. But nothing makes up for not having enough bits.

If you don't mind the performance hit, you can get away with unique timestamps but colliding hashes. In some hash map implementations the values associated with those colliding hashes simply end up in the same bucket and get looped over trying to find the unique key. I've already talked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26568802/1493294). But even if this still works when the hashes collide it still requires that the timestamps be unique or one event just ends up stepping on the other and deleting it when it's added to the hashmap.

If you know ahead of time what the rate of your events is going to be like you can be content that with choosing enough bits that the odds of identical timestamps are similar to winning the lottery.

Comment: This is a good answer; let's add some detail about the HashMap data structure: that it runs afoul of these issues you're pointing out here b/c it is a data structure that maps one key to at most *one value* (and may silently erase an old value at the same key).  Other hashing data structures can store multiple values for a single key, mitigating some of these issues.

Comment: @ErikEidt better?

Comment: One could write a central timestamp generating service to deal with overlaps, but it gets tricky.